# Let $G$ be group, $S \subset G$, $g \in G $. Prove: $gC_{G}(S)(g)^{-1} = C_{G}(gS(g)^{-1}).$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be group, $S \subset G$, $g \in G $. Prove:
>   $$gC_{G}(S)(g)^{-1} = C_{G}(gS(g)^{-1}), \forall g\in G.$$

I have managed to prove that $gC_{G}(S)(g)^{-1} \subseteq C_{G}(gS(g)^{-1})$, but I have troubles with this $ C_{G}(gS(g)^{-1}) \subseteq gC_{G}(S)(g)^{-1} $. I have tried to prove it by definition but I got stuck.
P.S. $C_{G}(S) = \{ g \in G \colon gsg^{-1} = s, \forall s \in S \}$.

Comment: [I found this.](https://yutsumura.com/conjugate-of-the-centralizer-of-a-set-is-the-centralizer-of-the-conjugate-of-the-set/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in C_G(gSg^{-1})$, then $$\forall s \in S, g \in G: g^{-1}xgs = g^{-1}xgsg^{-1}g.$$ Since $x$ commutes with $gsg^{-1}$ this is $$\underbrace{g^{-1}g}_{=e}sg^{-1}xg = sg^{-1}xg.$$ Hence for every $s \in S, g \in G$, $g^{-1}xg$ commutes with $s$ i.e. $g^{-1}xg \in C_G(S)$ and thus $x \in g^{-1}C_G(S)g$.